Can cold water induced arrhythmia be used diagnostically?
I ran across an extraordinary claim in the Sunday Times:

Professor Mike Tipton of the University of Portsmouth, who has been studying the effects of cold water on the body for 40 years, found that young and healthy individuals had a 1 to 3 per cent chance of cardiac arrhythmia when in cold water.
But when they were asked to hold their breath beforehand, that figure rose to 63 per cent. “It’s an incredible way of reproducing cardiac arrhythmias in otherwise fit and healthy individuals,” he said.

I didn't immediately find evidence for this on PubMed, but I wasn't very diligent in my search.  This abstract says 38% of a small group of test subjects, though I think this is summed up from 36 separate trials.
It is quite common to ask patients to wear a heart monitor for an extended period to check for occasional arrhythmias; but even then, who knows if they do what it would take to trigger an event during that period?  Can breath holding and/or cold water be used in a clinical setting to reveal underlying conduction disorders?

I imagined that the multiple fatalities reported in the article would have given you pause in asking this question. That was my first concern when I read your question: First do no harm. It's easier to avoid doing harm than to treat it once done. TBH, a term that would help you is using 'diagnostic procedure' in your Google Scholar search. And yes, it is useful in very specific and limited cases, particularly when cold water is already in play.

Is the induced arrhythmia from a simple combination of breath-holding and cold water so dangerous that you can't possibly prepare for it safely even in a hospital setting?  Amazing to consider when the social media kids are out doing this for a lark right now.

My comments are made with consideration. I gave you a tool for research. Read about it yourself. (Your own article outlined how dangerous this is. How many social media kids will die doing this? I actually lost an uncle this way.) You would be much less amazed if you worked in an ER or as a paramedic.

For it to be a diagnostic tool in a hospital setting would make it very expensive, and with its known risk factors it would have to be a very valuable tool to even be considered. So I think your question boils down to: Where's the evidence that it's possibly a tool with exceptional value? Asking if it could be used is just speculative and an interesting question from a research point of view, but asking if it could ever realistically be used in clinical medicine is a very different question. I think the answer is no.

As mentioned in the comments, establishing a kind of cold water testing to evaluate for possible arrhythmias in the controlled clinical environment is probably not feasible, largely for practical purposes of test set-up, etc.
However, consider the physiologic mechanism involved in inducing "cold water arrhythmias" and perhaps we can replicate the effects in our clinical labs. In the study that you linked, the authors postulate the physiologic mechanism to be as follows:

...these arrhythmias may have been due to conflicting chronotropic inputs to the heart. With continued submersion, both positive and negative chronotropic inputs to the heart are most likely to be occurring simultaneously just after the cessation of breath holding...The suggestion that an augmented sympathetic and parasympathetic influence on the heart may provoke these arrhythmias is supported by the absence or reduced incidence of arrhythmias in situations where the sympathetic or parasympathetic response predominates.

Thus, if we can find ways (which we have) to trigger or simulate the autonomic nervous system, we can attempt to provoke cardiac arrhythmias in a controlled setting. For example,

Exercise Stress Test: Through exercising, the patient will activate their sympathetic nervous system, potentially triggering clinically relevant arrhythmias. (Though exercise induced arrhythmias can be caused by other factors as well, such as ischemia.)
Electrophysiology Study: In the EP lab, electrophysiolgists perform various pacing maneuvers to try and induce arrhythmias, and will also adminster isoproterenol (a non-selective beta agonist) to make the patient more susceptible to arrhythmia induction upon pacing.
Tilt Table Test: The patient is strapped to a table that is gradually tilted upward. In some patients, this can elicit an exaggerate vagal response, and potentially diagnose bradyarrhythmias.

While I don't think that any of the current diagnostic tests exactly replicate this phenomenon of "cold water induced arrhythmia," there is also a question of how far you're willing to look for something that may or may not be of any clinical significance. As noted in the study:

Although the cause of the arrhythmias immediately after breath holding is of physiologic interest, from a practical viewpoint their clinical implication are unclear. The evidence from the present study suggests that although the arrhythmias occur in cold water in certain conditions, the majority have little clinical importance, being of short duration, supraventiucular in origin, and producing no symptoms. Alternatively, their occurrence may be significant in susceptible individuals, such as those with underlying conduction defects.

In sum, I think cold water testing can be used diagnostically; however, we have far more practical and safer testing modalities already in practice and we should utilize them first.
Resources:

Tipton, Mike & Kelleher, P & Golden, F. (1994). Supraventricular arrhythmias following breath-hold submersions in cold water. Undersea & hyperbaric medicine : Journal of the Undersea and Hyperbaric Medical Society, Inc. 21. 305-13. https://www.researchgate.net/publication/15248043_Supraventricular_arrhythmias_following_breath-hold_submersions_in_cold_water
Vilcant V, Zeltser R. Treadmill Stress Testing. [Updated 2023 Jun 20]. In: StatPearls [Internet]. Treasure Island (FL): StatPearls Publishing; 2024 Jan-. Available from: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK499903/
Guasch, E., & Mont, L. (2017). Diagnosis, pathophysiology, and management of exercise-induced arrhythmias. Nature reviews. Cardiology, 14(2), 88–101. https://doi.org/10.1038/nrcardio.2016.173
Majeed H, Sattar Y. Electrophysiologic Study Indications and Evaluation. [Updated 2023 Apr 3]. In: StatPearls [Internet]. Treasure Island (FL): StatPearls Publishing; 2024 Jan-. Available from: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK567719/
Thijs, R. D., Brignole, M., Falup-Pecurariu, C., Fanciulli, A., Freeman, R., Guaraldi, P., Jordan, J., Habek, M., Hilz, M., Traon, A. P., Stankovic, I., Struhal, W., Sutton, R., Wenning, G., & Van Dijk, J. G. (2021). Recommendations for tilt table testing and other provocative cardiovascular autonomic tests in conditions that may cause transient loss of consciousness : Consensus statement of the European Federation of Autonomic Societies (EFAS) endorsed by the American Autonomic Society (AAS) and the European Academy of Neurology (EAN). Clinical autonomic research : official journal of the Clinical Autonomic Research Society, 31(3), 369–384. https://doi.org/10.1007/s10286-020-00738-6

